# Python Keras: Overfitting a Keras MLP although loss curve doesn't look overfitted?

Tags: python, keras

I'm using Keras and Python to train a MLP Sequential model for classification of two classes. My Training Data has 247 features and I've got 17 Samples of class 1, 922 Samples of class 2. I use Smote Borderline Oversampling Algorithm to balance the dataset. I use Cross Validation with k=4 to validate the performance of precision and recall. For Training on each fold I plot the loss curve over training and validation, to estimate if the model is under- or overfitted.

I trained a model with 3 hidden layers, and reached 95% of precision and 71% for recall. The loss function plot for each fold doesn't seem to be overfitted. (I'm not allowed by stackoverflow to post the image). **But the evaluation of this model is worse, than with a model whose training precision and recall is worse.**

**Is this overfitting? And how can I detect it before evaluation?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With verbal-only questions (no code, plots, or data), it is highly unlikely that anyone here will be able to help you...

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect overfitting simply from the learning curve. The definition of overfitting is when your model does extremely well on the training set, and poorly on your evaluation set, which is exactly what you're reporting. 
In this case, I suspect the main problem is the unbalanced dataset. You can verify the spread of both classes in each of your sets (training, validation folds and test set) and see how your model performs on the minority class.

Comment: So I can't detect overfitting before evaluating the model? I thought the validation error would rise again..

Comment: In general, you can. It's the reason why we use a validation set. But in case of such a small number of samples from the minority class, you can perform well on your validation set by sheer luck / bad distribution across datasets. Did you check the number of samples in each partition of the dataset?

Comment: Also, I would advice you to try to tackle the problem as an "anomaly detection" task rather than binary classification. Your class ratio is so low (< 1%) that it would be difficult for any balancing algorithm to correct it.